# Calculate the number of days between two dates

Tags: java, datetime

This program uses user-input variables to calculate the `iDays` a person has been alive for (or the `iDays` between two input dates), taking into account for leap years and `iDays` in each month.

Can I please have some feedback on my code formatting and if you think this would get good marks?

```
//-------- Author: pumpkin

//-------- Date created: 10 April 2017

//-------- Date last changed: 17 April 2017

//-------- This program uses user-input variables to calculate the iDays a person has been alive for 

//-------- (or the iDays between two input dates), taking into account for leap years and iDays in each month.

//-------- Input: This file only reads the user input into the console. 

//-------- Output: None, or to console.


import java.util.Scanner;

public class Stage1 {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // declaration of variables
                    int iBirthYear, iBirthMonth, iBirthDay, iPresentYear, iPresentMonth, iPresentDay, iDaysAlive;

         // scanners, which will tell the program that it needs to scan the user input for the value of the variable that i've declared
        Scanner iBirthY = new Scanner(System.in);

        Scanner iBirthM = new Scanner(System.in);

        Scanner iBirthD = new Scanner(System.in);

        Scanner iPresentY = new Scanner(System.in);

        Scanner iPresentM = new Scanner(System.in);

        Scanner iPresentD = new Scanner(System.in);


        // asks user to input birth dates

        System.out.println("Please enter the year you were born: ");
            //takes input value and sets it to iBirthYear
                iBirthYear = iBirthY.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Please enter the month you were born: ");
            //takes input value and sets it to iBirthMonth  
                iBirthMonth = iBirthM.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Please enter the date you were born: ");
            //takes input value and sets it to iBirthDay    
                iBirthDay = iBirthD.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Please enter the current year: ");
            //takes input value and sets it to iPresentYear 
                iPresentYear = iPresentY.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Please enter the current month: ");
            //takes input value and sets it to iPresentMonth
                iPresentMonth = iPresentM.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Please enter the current day: ");
            //takes input value and sets it to iPresentDay  
                iPresentDay = iPresentD.nextInt();


/**     this is the if statements that calculate for leap years. 

*       both if/else statements do the same thing, just for the birth and present variables

*       if the month is jan or feb add 13 to the value of iMonth and subtract 1 from iYear

*       otherwise add one to iMonth and leave iYear as is.

**/ 

        if (iBirthMonth <= 2){
            iBirthMonth = iBirthMonth + 13;
            iBirthYear = iBirthYear - 1;
        }
        else {
            iBirthMonth = iBirthMonth + 1;
            iBirthYear = iBirthYear;
        }

        if (iPresentMonth <=2){
            iPresentMonth = iPresentMonth + 13;
            iPresentYear = iPresentYear - 1;
        }
        else {
            iPresentMonth = iPresentMonth + 1;
            iPresentYear = iPresentYear;
        }

//------------ the actual calculation between the dates. its the same calculation subtracted.   

        iDaysAlive = (((1461 * iPresentYear)/4) + ((153*iPresentMonth)/5) + (iPresentDay)) -
                    (((1461 * iBirthYear)/4) + ((153*iBirthMonth)/5) + (iBirthDay));

            System.out.println("You have been alive for: " + iDaysAlive + " days!");

    }

}
```

Comment: Your algorithm is wrong since not all months have the same number of days, and since leap years are at fixed dates.

Comment: IMHO use the java8 date time apis. Or Joda time if java8 is not available.
If its a homework then at-least look up how those apis do the calculations.

Comment: @Dexter I'm not allowed to use Java8 date time :(

Comment: @RolandIllig, I'm fairly sure I've tested it for all possibilities, I tested people born before February and after, born in leap years and not born in leap years, I tested for people born on Feb 29th as well and everything worked as tested with an online age calculator

Comment: Please add to the question what you told @Dexter, and add the homework tag.

Answer (score 1):

I see some code smell:

- A single `Scanner` instance is enough, there's no need to create multiple `Scanner`s
- Magic numbers: you should move 1461, 153, 13, etc. to constants with a meaningful name
- Readability: only one variable declaration per line
- Useless comments: "takes input value and sets it to XYZ" is an obvious statement, there is no need to fulfil your code with *noise*